# Objective C: Exchanging Data with Web Service (MySQL) without php

Tags: sql, objective-c, web-services, nsurlrequest

Since there are many examples to send the queries to the Web Service (e. g. MySQL) using php file as the intermediator, I wonder if is it possible to write the code with objective c to do it without the php code at all.

If it is possible, a piece of code would be welcome because I have no idea how to send the SQL query that way. Perhaps to use NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLConnection?

Frameworks are not the preference.

Comment: The Objective-C code on the iOS device will be the same no matter what language the web service is written in.

Comment: Can objective C be run on a web-server? If it can can you create a web service with Objective C? PHP is on the server side. If you want to connect your devices straight to your database you are opening yourself a whole world of maintenance pain and nightmares.

Comment: Do you mean that Objective C should be on the server side as well?